# Using .indexOf() with ArrayList<String>

Tags: java, arrays

I am attempting to create a battleship game using Java. The actual game works, but I ran into a surprising (for me) issue along the way. The code below generates a random location from a grid of 49 values that a user has to guess from. As a debugging tool, I figured I would print out the index of the ArrayList's number value, but I got a -1 (found out that means a value not found). Why didn't it return a number, considering my math was right?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GameHelper 
{
String alphabet = "abcdefg";
private int gridLength=7;
private int gridSize=49;
private int [] grid = new int [gridSize];
private int comCount=0;

public String getUserInput(String prompt)
{
    String inputLine=null;
    System.out.println(prompt);

    try
    {
        BufferedReader is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        inputLine=is.readLine();
        if (inputLine.equals(null))
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Buffered Reader Failure");
    }
    return inputLine;
}


public ArrayList <String> placeDotCom (int size)
{
    ArrayList <String> alphaCells = new ArrayList <String>();

    String temp=null;
    int [] coords=new int[size];
    int attempts=0;
    boolean success=false;
    int location=0;

    comCount++;
    int incr=1;
    if((comCount%2)==1)
    {
        incr=gridLength;
    }

    while (!success & attempts++ < 200)
    {
        location = (int)(Math.random()*gridSize);
        int x=0;
        success=true;
        while (success && x < size)
        {
            if (grid[location] ==0)
            {
                coords[x++]=location;
                location+=incr;
                if(location >= gridSize)
                {
                    success = false;
                }
                if(x>0 && (location % gridLength ==0))
                {
                    success = false;
                }
            }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("used" + location);
                    success=false;
                }
            }
        }


        int x=0;
        int row=0;
        int column=0;

        while(x < size)
        {
            grid[coords[x]] = 1;
            row = (int)(coords[x]/gridLength);
            column = coords[x] % gridLength;
            temp = String.valueOf(alphabet.charAt(column));

            alphaCells.add(temp.concat(Integer.toString(row)));
            x++;
        }
        System.out.println("coord "+x+" = "+alphaCells.get(x-1));
        return alphaCells;
    }

}
```

My attempted call:

```
for (DotCom dcset : dc)
{
ArrayList <String> newLocation = helper.placeDotCom(3);
dcset.setLocationCells(newLocation);
System.out.println(newLocation.indexOf(1));
}
```

I figured this was the only relevant code. If you would like me to post more, please tell me. This is my first time posting, and I'm not sure I asked this question correctly. Is this too vague?

Comment: "*`if (inputLine.equals(null))`*" - This will either return `false` or throw a `NullPointerException`

Comment: But what do you want to do? `indexOf()` on a list expects an object as the argument, is that what you're looking for, an Integer (1) or did you mean to call `get(1)` or...?

Comment: Why would you expect `indexOf(1)` on an `ArrayList <String>` to ever find anything? An `Integer` value (`1`) is **never** equal to a `String` value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the documentation of `ArrayList#indexOf(Object o)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf(java.lang.Object))

> Returns the index of the first occurrence of the specified element in this list, or `-1` if this list does not contain the element. More formally, returns the lowest index `i` such that `Objects.equals(o, get(i))`, or `-1` if there is no such index.

Notice that the method expects an `Object` as parameter (this has historical reasons, it stems from the dark ages where no generics existed in Java and all containers used `Object`).

Now, you declared `ArrayList <String> newLocation` and call `.indexOf(1)` on this object. The passed `int`-value gets [autoboxed](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) into an [`Integer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html). Since your `newLocation`-list contains only `String`s, the passed `Integer` cannot be found in the list. Thus, it returns a `-1`.

---

A remark on your code: As I wrote [in my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51125186/using-indexof-with-arrayliststring/51125304#comment89235367_51125186), `inputLine.equals(null)` will either return `false` (if `inputLine` is not `null`) or throw a `NullPointerException` (if `inputLine` is `null`). This is due to the fact that if the program tries to access an attribute or method on a `null`-reference, a `NullPointerException` will be thrown. Just write `inputLine == null` (in this case, `==` is correct). An alternative solution was [proposed by Szychan in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51125186/using-indexof-with-arrayliststring/51125304#comment89243762_51125304): You can use [`Objects.isNull(inputLine)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#isNull(java.lang.Object)) to check whether `inputLine` is `null`.

Comment: Ah, my mistake. I thought it worked like .substring (that using 1 as a parameter would return the object occupying the first part of ArrayList<>).

Comment: I prefer using Objects.isNull( object ) method . better readability.

Comment: @Szychan thank you for the comment! I incorporated your recommendation in my answer.